# EF Code First Cascade Deleting entries with multiple one-to-many relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I have the following tables:

```
public class Household
{
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  // other stuff

  public virtual ICollection<Debt> Debts
    {
        get { return this.debts; }
        set { this.debts = value; }
    }
}

public class Expense
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //other stuff

    public virtual ICollection<Debt> Debts
    {
        get { return this.debts; }
        set { this.debts = value; }
    }
}
public class Debt
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //other stuff

    [Required]
    public int HouseholdId { get; set; }

    public virtual Household Household { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ExpenseId { get; set; }

    public virtual Expense Expense { get; set; }
}
```

As we can see, every Debt belongs to a specific Household and a specific Expense, thus the two one-to-many relationships (one Household - many Debts,one Expense - many Debts). I am currently trying to implement cascade deleting for both those relationships,meaning that if I was to delete a Household OR an Expense, all of its associated Debts would be deleted as well. I am trying to use the OnModelCreating() method,but with little success. This is what I've tried:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Debt>()
.HasRequired(h => h.Expense)
.WithMany(b => b.Debts)
.HasForeignKey(h => h.ExpenseId)
.WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

    modelBuilder
.Entity<Debt>()
.HasRequired(h => h.Household)
.WithMany(b => b.Debts)
.HasForeignKey(h => h.HouseholdId)
.WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

If I have both WillCascadeDelete's with TRUE, I get the following exception

```
 Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint '' on table  
may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. 
Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints
```

However, if either one of the WillCascadeDelete's is FALSE (doesn't matter which one), everything works, except the relationship which has had it's CASCADE DELETE switched off. For example, if I turn off the Debt->Household one, I can delete an Expense and its Debts get automatically cascade deleted, but if I try to delete a Household, I get a Foreign Key exception.

Is there any way I can enable CASCADE DELETE for both relationships? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried your configuration in a simple console application project with latest EF version, and it worked like a charm. Try updating your Entity Framework version or searching for another reason for this behavior.

Comment: Most probably there is something inside *"other stuff"* in your `Household` and `Expense` entities (a common cascade delete path) that is causing that.

Comment: @IvanStoev Not really, the exception concerns only the HouseholdID and Raderick I'm using 6.1.3 already.

Comment: @user3554176 Ok, look from the other (our) side. Try the same as Raderik - create a new console app with EF and create a db with just the classes/configuration above. Can you duplicate the problem?